# How to use the variables of a simulink model in matlab m file?

Tags: algorithm, simulink, s-function, matlab

I hope my keywords describe my situation. Basically, I'm working with SMC (Sliding Mode Control) in Simulink using simulink blocks and S Function blocks. Now, I want to use DE (Differential Evolution) algorithm, to determine the parameters of SMC that gives the best results. DE implemented by two m files, one of them contain a function for objective function (this need by DE), and the other one contain the rest of DE algorithm, used to running. What I did, is that, I converted one m file, to s function because it need some variables from the Simulink Model, my question is that,  now I want to use the value of the objective function in the other m file (DE algorithm) to run the DE to make some iterations. Hopefully, I'm clear.
I found some stuff [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/42036-use-a-m-file-to-import-variables-in-to-a-simulink-matlab-function-box), but it seems, I'm looking exactly for the opposite scenario.

Comment: So, my first thought is that there is some special reason that you cannot convert the second file to a Simulink s-function? In that case, I'm afraid your only option might be to manually save each needed variable to the workspace at each time step. You should be able to do this using [`assignin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html).

Answer (score 0):

Let's define your two DE files first:

- **DE1**: contains a function for objective function;
- **DE2**: contains the rest of DE algorithm.

As far as I understood, you have converted DE2 into S-function, and wanted to use the variables in DE1 for iterations.

1. If the variables in DE1 are constant, then using [constant](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/constant.html) block
   in Simlink may solve your problem. Simply put those variables in the
   constant block and connect to DE2 as inputs.
2. If the variables in DE1 are varying during the iteration, then
   converting DE1 into S-function should be the right way to do it.